# magento 2 how to get the product object in product detail tab

Tags: php, magento, magento2

can anyone guide me on how I can load or get the product object on the detail tab
https://prnt.sc/t1dpay
I want to display the data on a detail page by loading the product object from 
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In Magento there is the `Magento\Framework\Registry` class which contains (among other things) the "current product", in case of the product detail page that would be the product shown on the page.

`Magento\Framework\Registry` is deprecated but I've not yet found a good alternative. Because it's deprecated most of the time I create a class which does only one thing, get the desired value from the registry. It's a middle ground between using the deprecated class itself directly or "rewriting it", it encapsulates the deprecated class and can be very easily swapped out if necessary in the future (either the whole class or specifically the implementation of `get()`).

```php
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class MyCurrentProduct {
    protected $registry;

    public function get(): ProductInterface {
        return $registry->get('current_product');
    }
}
```

I left some things out of the example because I don't like posting a copy-pastable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the registry, a much better option is to use the product repository.

Since you wish to grab the current product from the product detail page, that product id is available as a parameter from the URL:

[image]

You can then use the `RequestInterface` to grab an instance of the request object, and grab that specific parameter with:

```php
$productId = $this->request->getParam('id');
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
```

Here's the full code of doing this with a ViewModel:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Macademy\ProductInfo\ViewModel;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class MyViewModel implements ArgumentInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private RequestInterface $request,
        private ProductRepository $productRepository,
    ) {}

    /**
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        $productId = $this->request->getParam('id');
        return $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    }
}
```